# Merge Multiple Qt installation

Tags: qt

There are multiple installation version in Qt [download website](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-opensource-linux-x64-online.run) for each platform. As far as I can understand is the difference between those installation version is it's SDK that it contains. I've downloaded two version, Qt-5.4.1 for Linux 64-bit and Qt-5.4.1 for android and I installed android version. But, when I install Qt for linux version, Qt installer refuse to install in the same directory. So, can I merge those two version in one directory? I just thinking that if I install another version in another directory and then copy it to android version will give me problem.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this shouldn't be an issue.

What you could do is to download the Qt Online Installer and select all packages that you want Android / Linux / Source Codes / Plugins etc. and install it to a folder of your choice.

Everything that you selected will be installed into the Qt folder which you can later on modify using the `MaintenanceTool` in your install directory.

---

Alternatively your structure should be like

```
/Qt5.4.1/
    ...files
    /5.4
    /Tools
    /...
```

Make sure when installing you select `Qt5.4.1` as folder and not any subfolder

---

Worst case:

Make a folder named `Qt` and inside there install your different installations for example like:

```
/Qt/
    /Qt5.4.1Linux
    /Qt5.4.1Android
    /Qt5.4.1whatever
```

Comment: My internet connection is slow. That's why I downloaded offline installer. Online installer download speed usually is slower than regular download speed. It will take two days if I use online installer. And the `MaintenanceTool` that is provided by offline installer if different in both offline installer that I've downloaded. The tool just provide what necessary for it's installer.

Comment: @BagolDaplun updated, other than that what's wrong with having multiple installs?

Comment: The installer refuse to install on the same directory. The wrong thing is multiple installs take double space. And if possible I want to use single Qt creator for both version.

Comment: @BagolDaplun multiple installations into a single folder take the same space as having them in different. ( also it's 2015 who's worried about disk space anymore :p )

Comment: I just want to be as KISS as possible because I'm running Arch Linux ;)

Comment: I think you can't do it using current installer, but it is possible when you buld qt from source.